# Dismiss two UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have search around the web and there´s a lot of question like this, but i cant find the answer, it seems like everyone uses `navigationcontroller` and i am just using `uiviewcontroller` i am showing a UIViewcntroller like this:

> [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];

When i realease the controller to show a controller before i use:

> [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

What i have is A->B->C in C i need to dismiss C and B UIViewControllers, how do i achieve this?

Comment: can't you just dismiss `B` view controller?

Comment: If i dismiss B before calling C, A is showed, if i dismiss B after C then nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach :

```
 [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

From `C` where you want to go to views back just put this line and it will lead you directly to `A`.

You can also use `NSNotificationCenter`.

Hope this helps you.